# Crystal Report String Comparison with spaces

Tags: string, crystal-reports, comparison, string-comparison

I want to compare two stings in Crystal Reports (CR). For the string comparison am using this function.

```
(IF({?p_promotion_grid} = ' ' and not(isnull({@promotionGrid})))
THEN {@promotionGrid} LIKE '*'
ELSE {@promotionGrid} = {?p_promotion_grid} )
```

when the promotionGrid value is one word the comparison works. However when the String contains spaces. e.g.- AAA BBB it will not work.

How to compare this string?

I tried this StrCmp(str1, str2,compare), but even when str1 and str2 are same the ELSE condition won't get true. Any ideas how to do the string comparison?

Comment: When you directly print the {?p_promotion_grid} what report shows?

Comment: It shows AAA BBB. Should I compare them like this AAABBB?

Comment: I am not clear with your then statement. What you are trying to do there?

Comment: I thought to remove the space between the two words and compare..because when the space is present it will say the strings are not equal even when they are equal.

Comment: Ok. The string to which you are comparing is AAABBB and the parameter is giving you AAA BBB. Right?

Answer (score 0):

```
if instr({Table.Remarks},"Bank") > 0 then
    /// true section
else
    // false section
end if
```